# How to validate From vs To dates using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am using Nestjs Crud to build certain CRUD endpoints. In one of the PATCH/POST endpoints, I am trying to validate dates that I am getting from the Frontend (validFrom, ValidTo).

Conditions:

1. ValidFrom date should be greater than or equal to today's date.
2. ValidTo date should be in the future (not today ofcourse)
3. ValidTo should be greater than validFrom.

This is the code that is there:

```
public async validateDates(validFrom: string, validTo: string): Promise<void> {
    if (moment(validTo).isSameOrBefore(moment().startOf('day'))) {
      throw new BadRequestException('validTo date should be should be greater than todays date.');
    } else if (moment(validFrom).isBefore(moment().startOf('day'))) {
      throw new BadRequestException('validFrom date should not be in the past.');
    } else if (moment(validFrom).isSameOrAfter(moment(validTo))) {
      throw new BadRequestException('validFrom date should be less than validTo date.');
    }
  }
```

IF I try to enter validTo date as today's date, I get the error 'validFrom date should be less than validTo date', but ideally, I should be getting the error ''validTo date should be should be greater than todays date.'

Is there a better way to perform these validations?

Answer (score 0):

What do you pass into the `validFrom` and `validTo`? If it contains time then you would need to do something like `moment(validTo).startOf('day').isSameOrBefore(moment().startOf('day'))`